# Deserialize a object containing a nested json string with escaped characters to a nested POCO

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

We are receiving json message which include an embedded json object with escaped characters.

As an example the escaped Json `string rawMessage = "{\"lte\": \"{\\\"lst\\\":5,\\\"lrs\\\":19,\\\"lrq\\\":3}\"}";`

This is obviously quick difficult to test with and has the potentially for countless typing errors, so we would like to find a cleaner way of working with POCOs rather than raw strings. Unfortunately deserializing the embedded message isn't straight forward.

The string above has an equivalent model of:

```
public class Message{
    public string lte { get; set;}
}
```

Using this in code we can do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(rawMessage)` which deserialzies the string to the Message model, and if we hover over lte in the debugger shows the embedded Json.

What I'd like to do is Deserialize to the full POCO which is:

```
public class Message{
    public Lte lte { get; set;}
}

public class Lte{
    public int lst { get; set;}
    public int lrs { get; set;}
    public int lrq { get; set;}
}
```

However this results in a casting exception when `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(rawMessage)` is run.

Interestingly, if you Deserialize twice the embedded json converts ok. Going back to the string version of Message you can run:

```
var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(rawMessage);
var embeddedMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Lte>(message.lte);
```

To retrieve the embedded POCO.

Is this possible with one Deserialize call, maybe just missing some decorators?

Comment: What is the problem in using two deserialize calls?

Comment: Not really a problem, it just seems unnecessary when it would normally be a single Deserialize call to get the Parent and Child objects.

Comment: @RossHalliday It is unnecessary to write the hundreds line of code where  you can only need one line.

Comment: I've left you an update on the answer. Check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution would be to write a custom `JsonConverter`.

If I understood correctly, you are using `Newtonsoft.Json`. Here is a custom JSON converter for your model:

```cs
public class MessageConverter : JsonConverter<Message> {
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Message value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        writer.WriteToken(JsonToken.StartObject);
        writer.WritePropertyName("lte");
        writer.WriteValue(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value.lte));
        writer.WriteToken(JsonToken.EndObject);
    }

    public override Message ReadJson(JsonReader     reader,
                                     Type           objectType,
                                     Message        existingValue,
                                     bool           hasExistingValue,
                                     JsonSerializer serializer) {
        string? lteString = null;
        while (reader.Read()) {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName && (string)reader.Value! == "lte") {
                lteString = reader.ReadAsString();
                break;
            }
        }
        while(reader.Read()) {}

        if (lteString is null) {
            throw new JsonException("lte property missing");
        }
        return new Message { lte = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Lte>(lteString) };
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
string rawMessage  = "{\"lte\": \"{\\\"lst\\\":5,\\\"lrs\\\":19,\\\"lrq\\\":3}\"}";
var    message     = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(rawMessage, new MessageConverter());
```

---

*UPDATE*

You could also apply a `[JsonConverter(typeof(MessageConverter))]` to the `Message` class:

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(MessageConverter))]
public class Message {
    public Lte lte { get; set; }
}

string rawMessage  = "{\"lte\": \"{\\\"lst\\\":5,\\\"lrs\\\":19,\\\"lrq\\\":3}\"}";
var    message     = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(rawMessage);
```

This way you wouldn't need to use `new MessageConverter()` every time.

---

*UPDATE*

I came up with a little simplier solution. Write a converter only for `Lte` and apply it directly in the `Message` class on the `lte` property via an attribute. Looks much cleaner and allows to extend `Message` class safely without the need to modify the converter:

```cs
public class Message {
    [JsonConverter(typeof(LteConverter))]
    public Lte lte { get; set; }
}

public class Lte {
    public int lst { get; set; }
    public int lrs { get; set; }
    public int lrq { get; set; }
}

public class LteConverter : JsonConverter<Lte> {
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Lte value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        writer.WriteValue(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public override Lte ReadJson(JsonReader     reader,
                                 Type           objectType,
                                 Lte            existingValue,
                                 bool           hasExistingValue,
                                 JsonSerializer serializer) {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Lte>((string)reader.Value!);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
string rawMessage  = "{\"lte\": \"{\\\"lst\\\":5,\\\"lrs\\\":19,\\\"lrq\\\":3}\"}";
var    message     = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(rawMessage);
```

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @RossHalliday check my latest update. It is much cleaner and allows to extend `Message` class safely without the need to modify the converter

Comment: Also, the way I've written the serialization is to convert the `Lte` object back to string as it was originally. If you want a different behaviour, you would need to change the `WriteJson` method

Answer (score -1):

you can parse at first,after this you can deserialize

```
var lteJson = (string) JObject.Parse(rawMessage)["lte"];
Lte lte = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Lte>(lteJson);
```

or just in one line

```
Lte lte = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Lte>((string)JObject.Parse(rawMessage)["lte"]);
```